# SQLite db file is only read at the startup of the app

Tags: ios, sqlite, swift2

I have an issue with my code that I hope maybe som of you can help me out with. 
I have a "kindoff" dictionary app where the user can search for abbreviations. 
The datamodel is build using an SQLite database. In my first version the data.db file was only stored locally, but since I have to make a lot of data updates I don't wanna update en whole app every time. So I have made a version that gets the data.db file from a server instead. 
My problem is that the user have to quit og restart the app to get the updated version. Somehow, even if the new file is copied to the directory the sqldb class does'nt read the new file. Any idea how to make som code the gets the dbclass to read the new file, while the app is running?
Here is the code the copies the new file to the directory

```
    func executeDownloadTask(){
        if Reachability.isConnectedToNetwork() == true{
        print("just Checking")
        let backgroundSessionConfiguration =     NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("backgroundSession")
        backgroundSession = NSURLSession(configuration: backgroundSessionConfiguration, delegate: self,delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())


        let the_path:String = UpdateDbFile.findPathInDocDir("data.db");// get the path for the data.db file
        UpdateDbFile.deleteFilewithPath(the_path) // delete the existing file
        startDownload()     // download the updated dbfile

        }
    }
```

Heres the SQLiteDb class that I use.

```
    //
    //  SQLiteDB.swift
    //  TasksGalore
    //
    //  Created by Fahim Farook on 12/6/14.
    //  Copyright (c) 2014 RookSoft Pte. Ltd. All rights reserved.
    //

    import Foundation
    #if os(iOS)
    import UIKit
    #else
    import AppKit
    #endif


    let SQLITE_DATE = SQLITE_NULL + 1
    internal let SQLITE_STATIC = unsafeBitCast(0, sqlite3_destructor_type.self)
    internal let SQLITE_TRANSIENT = unsafeBitCast(-1, sqlite3_destructor_type.self)




    // MARK:- SQLColumn Class - Column Definition
    class SQLColumn {
    var value:AnyObject? = nil
    var type:CInt = -1

    init(value:AnyObject, type:CInt) {
    //      println("SQLiteDB - Initialize column with type: \(type), value: \(value)")

        self.value = value
        self.type = type
    }

    // New conversion functions
    func asString()->String {
        switch (type) {
            case SQLITE_INTEGER, SQLITE_FLOAT:
                return "\(value!)"

            case SQLITE_TEXT:
                return value as! String

            case SQLITE_BLOB:
                if let str = NSString(data:value as! NSData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    return str as String
                } else {
                    return ""
                }

            case SQLITE_NULL:
                return ""

            case SQLITE_DATE:
                let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
                fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                return fmt.stringFromDate(value as! NSDate)

            default:
                return ""
        }
    }

    func asInt()->Int {
        switch (type) {
            case SQLITE_INTEGER, SQLITE_FLOAT:
                return value as! Int

            case SQLITE_TEXT:
                let str = value as! NSString
                return str.integerValue

            case SQLITE_BLOB:
                if let str = NSString(data:value as! NSData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    return str.integerValue
                } else {
                    return 0
                }

            case SQLITE_NULL:
                return 0

            case SQLITE_DATE:
                return Int((value as! NSDate).timeIntervalSince1970)

            default:
                return 0
        }
    }

    func asDouble()->Double {
        switch (type) {
            case SQLITE_INTEGER, SQLITE_FLOAT:
                return value as! Double

            case SQLITE_TEXT:
                let str = value as! NSString
                return str.doubleValue

            case SQLITE_BLOB:
                if let str = NSString(data:value as! NSData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    return str.doubleValue
                } else {
                    return 0.0
                }

            case SQLITE_NULL:
                return 0.0

            case SQLITE_DATE:
                return (value as! NSDate).timeIntervalSince1970

            default:
                return 0.0
        }
    }

    func asData()->NSData? {
        switch (type) {
            case SQLITE_INTEGER, SQLITE_FLOAT:
                let str = "\(value)" as NSString
                return str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            case SQLITE_TEXT:
                let str = value as! NSString
                return str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            case SQLITE_BLOB:
                return value as? NSData

            case SQLITE_NULL:
                return nil

            case SQLITE_DATE:
                let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
                fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                let str = fmt.stringFromDate(value as! NSDate)
                return str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

            default:
                return nil
        }
    }

    func asDate()->NSDate? {
        switch (type) {
            case SQLITE_INTEGER, SQLITE_FLOAT:
                let tm = value as! Double
                return NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:tm)

            case SQLITE_TEXT:
                let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
                fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                return fmt.dateFromString(value as! String)

            case SQLITE_BLOB:
                if let str = NSString(data:value as! NSData, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    let fmt = NSDateFormatter()
                    fmt.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
                    return fmt.dateFromString(str as String)
                } else {
                    return nil
                }

            case SQLITE_NULL:
                return nil

            case SQLITE_DATE:
                return value as? NSDate

            default:
                return nil
        }
    }

    func description()->String {
        return "Type: \(type), Value: \(value)"
    }
}

    // MARK:- SQLRow Class - Row Definition
class SQLRow {
    var data = Dictionary<String, SQLColumn>()

    subscript(key: String) -> SQLColumn? {
        get {
            return data[key]
        }

        set(newVal) {
            data[key] = newVal
        }
    }

    func description()->String {
        return data.description
    }
}

    // MARK:- SQLiteDB Class - Does all the work
class SQLiteDB{



           let DB_NAME = "data.db"

           let QUEUE_LABLE = "SQLiteDB"
    private var db:COpaquePointer = nil
    private var queue:dispatch_queue_t
    private var fmt = NSDateFormatter()
    private var GROUP = ""
    var newFileName = " "
    var recentFileName = "Bøsse "


    struct Static {
        static var instance:SQLiteDB? = nil
        static var token:dispatch_once_t = 0
    }

    class func sharedInstance() -> SQLiteDB! {
        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            Static.instance = self.init(gid:"")
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    class func sharedInstance(gid:String) -> SQLiteDB! {
        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            Static.instance = self.init(gid:gid)
        }
        return Static.instance!
    }

    required init(gid:String) {


        assert(Static.instance == nil, "Singleton already initialized!")
        GROUP = gid
        // Set queue
        queue = dispatch_queue_create(QUEUE_LABLE, nil)
        // Set up for file operations
        let fm = NSFileManager.defaultManager()


        let dbName:String = String.fromCString(DB_NAME)!


        var docDir = ""
        // Is this for an app group?
        if GROUP.isEmpty {
            // Get path to DB in Documents directory


            docDir = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory,.UserDomainMask, true)[0] as String



        } else {
            // Get path to shared group folder
            if let url = fm.containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier(GROUP) {
                docDir = url.path!
            } else {
                assert(false, "Error getting container URL for group: \(GROUP)")
            }
        }


        let path = docDir.NS.stringByAppendingPathComponent(dbName)

                     print(path)



        // Check if copy of DB is there in Documents directory
        if !(fm.fileExistsAtPath(path)) {

            // The database does not exist, so copy to Documents directory
           if let from = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath?.NS.stringByAppendingPathComponent(dbName) {
                var error:NSError?
                do {
                    try fm.copyItemAtPath(from, toPath: path)
                    print("restart the app to get updated data")
                } catch let error1 as NSError {
                    error = error1
                    print("SQLiteDB - failed to copy writable version of DB!")
                    print("Error - \(error!.localizedDescription)")
                    return
                }
            }
        }


        // Open the DB



            let cpath = path.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            let error = sqlite3_open(cpath!, &db)
            if error != SQLITE_OK {
                // Open failed, close DB and fail
                print("SQLiteDB - failed to open DB!")
                sqlite3_close(db)
        }



        fmt.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
    }


    deinit {
        closeDatabase()
    }

    private func closeDatabase() {
        if db != nil {
            // Get launch count value
            let ud = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
            var launchCount = ud.integerForKey("LaunchCount")
            launchCount--
            print("SQLiteDB - Launch count \(launchCount)")
            var clean = false
            if launchCount < 0 {
                clean = true
                launchCount = 500
            }
            ud.setInteger(launchCount, forKey: "LaunchCount")
            ud.synchronize()
            // Do we clean DB?
            if !clean {
                sqlite3_close(db)
                return
            }
            // Clean DB
            print("SQLiteDB - Optimize DB")
            let sql = "VACUUM; ANALYZE"
            if execute(sql) != SQLITE_OK {
                print("SQLiteDB - Error cleaning DB")
            }
            sqlite3_close(db)
        }
    }

    // Execute SQL with parameters and return result code
    func execute(sql:String, parameters:[AnyObject]?=nil)->CInt {
        var result:CInt = 0
        dispatch_sync(queue) {
            let stmt = self.prepare(sql, params:parameters)
            if stmt != nil {
                result = self.execute(stmt, sql:sql)
            }
        }
        return result
    }

    // Run SQL query with parameters
    func query(sql:String, parameters:[AnyObject]?=nil)->[SQLRow] {
        var rows = [SQLRow]()
        dispatch_sync(queue) {
            let stmt = self.prepare(sql, params:parameters)
            if stmt != nil {
                rows = self.query(stmt, sql:sql)
            }
        }
        return rows
    }

    // Show alert with either supplied message or last error
    func alert(msg:String) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
#if os(iOS)
            let alert = UIAlertView(title: "SQLiteDB", message:msg, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alert.show()
#else
            let alert = NSAlert()
            alert.addButtonWithTitle("OK")
            alert.messageText = "SQLiteDB"
            alert.informativeText = msg
            alert.alertStyle = NSAlertStyle.WarningAlertStyle
            alert.runModal()
#endif
        }
    }

    // Private method which prepares the SQL
    private func prepare(sql:String, params:[AnyObject]?)->COpaquePointer {
        var stmt:COpaquePointer = nil
        let cSql = sql.cStringUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        // Prepare
        let result = sqlite3_prepare_v2(self.db, cSql!, -1, &stmt, nil)
        if result != SQLITE_OK {
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
            if let error = String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(self.db)) {
                let msg = "SQLiteDB - failed to prepare SQL: \(sql), Error: \(error)"
                print(msg)
            }
            return nil
        }
        // Bind parameters, if any
        if params != nil {
            // Validate parameters
            let cntParams = sqlite3_bind_parameter_count(stmt)
            let cnt = CInt(params!.count)
            if cntParams != cnt {
                let msg = "SQLiteDB - failed to bind parameters, counts did not match. SQL: \(sql), Parameters: \(params)"
                print(msg)
                return nil
            }
            var flag:CInt = 0
            // Text & BLOB values passed to a C-API do not work correctly if they are not marked as transient.
            for ndx in 1...cnt {
//              println("Binding: \(params![ndx-1]) at Index: \(ndx)")
                // Check for data types
                if let txt = params![ndx-1] as? String {
                    flag = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, CInt(ndx), txt, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
                } else if let data = params![ndx-1] as? NSData {
                    flag = sqlite3_bind_blob(stmt, CInt(ndx), data.bytes, CInt(data.length), SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
                } else if let date = params![ndx-1] as? NSDate {
                    let txt = fmt.stringFromDate(date)
                    flag = sqlite3_bind_text(stmt, CInt(ndx), txt, -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT)
                } else if let val = params![ndx-1] as? Double {
                    flag = sqlite3_bind_double(stmt, CInt(ndx), CDouble(val))
                } else if let val = params![ndx-1] as? Int {
                    flag = sqlite3_bind_int(stmt, CInt(ndx), CInt(val))
                } else {
                    flag = sqlite3_bind_null(stmt, CInt(ndx))
                }
                // Check for errors
                if flag != SQLITE_OK {
                    sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
                    if let error = String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(self.db)) {
                        let msg = "SQLiteDB - failed to bind for SQL: \(sql), Parameters: \(params), Index: \(ndx) Error: \(error)"
                        print(msg)
                    }
                    return nil
                }
            }
        }
        return stmt
    }

    // Private method which handles the actual execution of an SQL statement
    private func execute(stmt:COpaquePointer, sql:String)->CInt {
        // Step
        var result = sqlite3_step(stmt)
        if result != SQLITE_OK && result != SQLITE_DONE {
            sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
            if let err = String.fromCString(sqlite3_errmsg(self.db)) {
                let msg = "SQLiteDB - failed to execute SQL: \(sql), Error: \(err)"
                print(msg)
            }
            return 0
        }
        // Is this an insert
        let upp = sql.uppercaseString
        if upp.hasPrefix("INSERT ") {
            // Known limitations: http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/last_insert_rowid.html
            let rid = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(self.db)
            result = CInt(rid)
        } else if upp.hasPrefix("DELETE") || upp.hasPrefix("UPDATE") {
            var cnt = sqlite3_changes(self.db)
            if cnt == 0 {
                cnt++
            }
            result = CInt(cnt)
        } else {
            result = 1
        }
        // Finalize
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
        return result
    }

    // Private method which handles the actual execution of an SQL query
    private func query(stmt:COpaquePointer, sql:String)->[SQLRow] {
        var rows = [SQLRow]()
        var fetchColumnInfo = true
        var columnCount:CInt = 0
        var columnNames = [String]()
        var columnTypes = [CInt]()
        var result = sqlite3_step(stmt)
        while result == SQLITE_ROW {
            // Should we get column info?
            if fetchColumnInfo {
                columnCount = sqlite3_column_count(stmt)
                for index in 0..<columnCount {
                    // Get column name
                    let name = sqlite3_column_name(stmt, index)
                    columnNames.append(String.fromCString(name)!)
                    // Get column type
                    columnTypes.append(self.getColumnType(index, stmt:stmt))
                }
                fetchColumnInfo = false
            }
            // Get row data for each column
            let row = SQLRow()
            for index in 0..<columnCount {
                let key = columnNames[Int(index)]
                let type = columnTypes[Int(index)]
                if let val:AnyObject = self.getColumnValue(index, type:type, stmt:stmt) {
//                      println("Column type:\(type) with value:\(val)")
                    let col = SQLColumn(value: val, type: type)
                    row[key] = col
                }
            }
            rows.append(row)
            // Next row
            result = sqlite3_step(stmt)
        }
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt)
        return rows
    }

    // Get column type
    private func getColumnType(index:CInt, stmt:COpaquePointer)->CInt {
        var type:CInt = 0
        // Column types - http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html (section 2.2 table column 1)
        let blobTypes = ["BINARY", "BLOB", "VARBINARY"]
        let charTypes = ["CHAR", "CHARACTER", "CLOB", "NATIONAL VARYING CHARACTER", "NATIVE CHARACTER", "NCHAR", "NVARCHAR", "TEXT", "VARCHAR", "VARIANT", "VARYING CHARACTER"]
        let dateTypes = ["DATE", "DATETIME", "TIME", "TIMESTAMP"]
        let intTypes  = ["BIGINT", "BIT", "BOOL", "BOOLEAN", "INT", "INT2", "INT8", "INTEGER", "MEDIUMINT", "SMALLINT", "TINYINT"]
        let nullTypes = ["NULL"]
        let realTypes = ["DECIMAL", "DOUBLE", "DOUBLE PRECISION", "FLOAT", "NUMERIC", "REAL"]
        // Determine type of column - http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/c_blob.html
        let buf = sqlite3_column_decltype(stmt, index)
//      println("SQLiteDB - Got column type: \(buf)")
        if buf != nil {
            var tmp = String.fromCString(buf)!.uppercaseString
            // Remove brackets
            let pos = tmp.positionOf("(")
            if pos > 0 {
                tmp = tmp.subStringTo(pos)
            }
            // Remove unsigned?
            // Remove spaces
            // Is the data type in any of the pre-set values?
//          println("SQLiteDB - Cleaned up column type: \(tmp)")
            if intTypes.contains(tmp) {
                return SQLITE_INTEGER
            }
            if realTypes.contains(tmp) {
                return SQLITE_FLOAT
            }
            if charTypes.contains(tmp) {
                return SQLITE_TEXT
            }
            if blobTypes.contains(tmp) {
                return SQLITE_BLOB
            }
            if nullTypes.contains(tmp) {
                return SQLITE_NULL
            }
            if dateTypes.contains(tmp) {
                return SQLITE_DATE
            }
            return SQLITE_TEXT
        } else {
            // For expressions and sub-queries
            type = sqlite3_column_type(stmt, index)
        }
        return type
    }
    // Get column value
    private func getColumnValue(index:CInt, type:CInt, stmt:COpaquePointer)->AnyObject? {
        // Integer
        if type == SQLITE_INTEGER {
            let val = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, index)
            return Int(val)
        }
        // Float
        if type == SQLITE_FLOAT {
            let val = sqlite3_column_double(stmt, index)
            return Double(val)
        }
        // Text - handled by default handler at end
        // Blob
        if type == SQLITE_BLOB {
            let data = sqlite3_column_blob(stmt, index)
            let size = sqlite3_column_bytes(stmt, index)
            let val = NSData(bytes:data, length: Int(size))
            return val
        }
        // Null
        if type == SQLITE_NULL {
            return nil
        }
        // Date
        if type == SQLITE_DATE {
            // Is this a text date
            let txt = UnsafePointer<Int8>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, index))
            if txt != nil {
                if let buf = NSString(CString:txt, encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding) {
                    let set = NSCharacterSet(charactersInString: "-:")
                    let range = buf.rangeOfCharacterFromSet(set)
                    if range.location != NSNotFound {
                        // Convert to time
                        var time:tm = tm(tm_sec: 0, tm_min: 0, tm_hour: 0, tm_mday: 0, tm_mon: 0, tm_year: 0, tm_wday: 0, tm_yday: 0, tm_isdst: 0, tm_gmtoff: 0, tm_zone:nil)
                        strptime(txt, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &time)
                        time.tm_isdst = -1
                        let diff = NSTimeZone.localTimeZone().secondsFromGMT
                        let t = mktime(&time) + diff
                        let ti = NSTimeInterval(t)
                        let val = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970:ti)
                        return val
                    }
                }
            }
            // If not a text date, then it's a time interval
            let val = sqlite3_column_double(stmt, index)
            let dt = NSDate(timeIntervalSince1970: val)
            return dt
        }
        // If nothing works, return a string representation
        let buf = UnsafePointer<Int8>(sqlite3_column_text(stmt, index))
        let val = String.fromCString(buf)
//      println("SQLiteDB - Got value: \(val)")
        return val
    }
}



public extension String {
    var NS: NSString { return (self as NSString) }
}
```

Hope you can give me some advice. Thanks

Comment: That's not enough information.  Where are you storing the database file?  When are you calling `executeDownloadTask()`?  Have you attempted to debug the issue by putting some breakpoints in that method?  This question doesn't really appear to be about sqlite3 at all, but rather about a simple invocation issue you have.

Comment: Okay, I will try to give you more information. I'm calling the `executeDownloadTask()` in `viewDidLoad()` in my root viewcontroller.

Comment: I also tried to call it using a button action and also tried in `viewDidAppear()`. And I get the same result. The file is downloaded but not read  untill i close and restart the app. I think you're right about the invocation issue. But where?

Comment: First thing first, is the method being invoked?  It does sound like it to me.  Next thing: you don't want to delete and re-download a file if you already have the latest version, so you'll need to work on that.  Finally (and probably what your real issue is): do you close the database before deleting it and re-open it after downloading it?

Comment: Thanks. I don't think that the database is closed before its deleted. So maybe that's my issue. And yes you're right I don't want to redownload the file if I already have the latest version. Thanks I will look at this

Comment: Hmm. Still not found a solution. I can close the database but I can't open it unless i restart the app